# Cancelling statement due to timeout PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am trying to execute the below SQL query, but it is giving me an error, because of large number of items I'm putting in the where clause.

For `column a` 85,000 items.

```
SELECT distinct a,b,count(*)
FROM X
where serverdatetime > NOW() - interval '5 days'
and b = '162' and a in ('..........')
group by a,b
```

Need help.

Comment: Are the values in `a` coming from another table in the same database? A regular database join with the proper index would likely solve this performance issue.

Comment: Got your point. It worked.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out!